# dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier never returns my reusable cell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've a *UITableViewController* with a lot of cell, but they all have the same configuration -- it's only the cell content which differs. Here is my `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method in my *UITableViewController*:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WSTableViewCell";

    WSTableViewCell *cell = (WSTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[WSTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    WSObject *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.textLabel setText:item.title];

    return cell;
}
```

Here is the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` in my custom *UITableViewCell*:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self.textLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]];
        [self.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:100.0/255.0 green:100.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        [self.textLabel setHighlightedTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:100.0/255.0 green:100.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
        [self.textLabel setNumberOfLines:2];
    }
    return self;
}
```

I've just noticed, that this `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` is called for every cell in the table view, and that the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` in the *UITableViewController* always returns *nil*. As far as I understand this mechanism with reusable cells, this kind of cell should only be initialized once when I use the same cell identifier. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cells are only reused when they are scrolled off-screen. Let's say one screen shows 11 cells, you will allocate 11 cells which are reused as you scroll.

Comment: Well you are right, that what happening for me. Are there any way to dequeue them earlier? I have a grid view on my iPad version, where 16 will be allocated. That's big overload, as I only need one to be allocated.

Comment: @DennisMadsen If you only have one cell, then you can only show one at a time. You can't show the same view in 2 places (or 16 places!) at the same time.